# Specification com Spring Data Jpa passando parametro null

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data, criteria, spring-jpa

Estou utilizando as Specifications Spring Data JPA, porém estou com uma dificuldade! Ao não passar nenhum parâmetro nos dois campos quero que ele me retorne todos os registros. Mas ao fazer a consulta ele está me retornando somente os que tem os dois respectivos campos null/vazio no banco!

```
      public class SistemaSpecs {

public static Specification<Sistema> descricao(String descricao) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> 
      builder.or(builder.equal(root.get(Sistema_.descricao),  descricao));
     }
public static Specification<Sistema> sigla(String sigla) {
    return (root, query, builder) -> 
      builder.or(builder.equal(root.get(Sistema_.sigla),sigla));
     }
  }
```

O método que chama e faz consulta é esse.

```
 public Page<Sistema> pesquisar(Sistema sistema, Pageable pageable) {
    Specifications<Sistema> where = 
         where(SistemaSpecs.descricao(sistema.getDescricao()))
            .or(SistemaSpecs.sigla(sistema.getSigla()));
     return sistemaRepository.findAll(where, pageable);
 }
```

Alguém como posso recuperar todos o registros quando o parametro passado for null, sem segundo a mesma estrutura ?

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que colocar uma verificação dentro da sua função para não efetuar a busca quando os parâmetros forem nulos.

```
public Page<Sistema> pesquisar(Sistema sistema, Pageable pageable) {
     if(sistema.getDescricao() != null && sistema.getSigla() != null){
          Specifications<Sistema> where = 
          where(SistemaSpecs.descricao(sistema.getDescricao()))
             .or(SistemaSpecs.sigla(sistema.getSigla()));
          return sistemaRepository.findAll(where, pageable);
    }else{
          return sistemaRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado Filipe Assad pelo comentário! Isso seria uma maneira que resolveria, porém não seria legal isso porque teria que fazer essa verificação em todo lugar da aplicação que utiliza a SistemaSpecs. E isso não seria uma maneira legal de se fazer!

Answer (score -1):

Na classe SistemaSpecs que vc criou cada método representa um critério para sua consulta, ai fica na responsabilidade do usuário da classe realizar as verificações, e como vc comentou, acaba gerando muito código se eu tiver que repetir as validações em todos os lugares que precisarei realizar esta consulta.

Minha sugestão é para que ao invés de criar uma classe com os métodos de critério de consulta, vc crie uma classe que implementa Specification e dentro desta classe vc defina suas cláusulas de consulta colocando as validações necessárias, dai suas validações estarão em um único lugar.

Apesar de não conhecer o código de sua classe Sistema vou criar um exemplo aleatório para exemplificar esta situação:

Temos a seguinte classe Entidade para estados (São Paulo, Rio de Janeiro, etc):

```
@Entity
    public classe Estado Serializable{

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private Long id;
        private String nomeEstado;
        private String sigla;

        //Contrutores, Gets e Sets
```

A partir desta classe você criará o seu repositorio (Estou entendo que esta usando esta abordagem), no entando o repositório deverá herdar a interface JpaSpecificationExecutor relacionado a entidade envolvida, no caso a classe Estado.

```
@Repository
public interface EsdadoRepository extends JpaRepository<Estado,Long >, JpaSpecificationExecutor<Estado> { 
    }
```

Ótimo, nosso cenário pronto! Agora vem a criação de uma classe que implementa a interface Specification referente a nossa entidade Estado. É nesta classe que iremos colocar nossos critérios e validações de campo.

```
public class EstadoSpecification implements Specification<Estado> {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        private String nomeEstado;
        private String sigla;

        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

    public EstadoSpecification(String nomeEstado,String sigla) {
        super();
        this.nomeEstado = nomeEstado;
        this.estado = sigla;
    }

    @Override
    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<ItemVendedor> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder builder) {

        if (!nomeEstado.isEmpty()) {
            predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(root.get("nomeEstado")), "%" + nomeEstado.toUpperCase() + "%"));; 
        }

        if(!sigla.isEmpty()) {
           predicates.add(builder.like(builder.upper(root.get("sigla")), "%" + sigla.toUpperCase() + "%"));;
        }   
        return builder.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[1]));
        }
}
```

Então, dentro de um método de consulta do estado em sua classe de serviço, vc informa os parâmetros de consulta (descrição e estado)da seguinte forma:

```
    public List<Estado> buscarEstados(String nomeEstado, String sigla) {

            Specification<Estado> spec = new EstadoSpecification(nomeEstado,estado); 

            List<Estado> lista = EstadoRepository.findAll(spec);

    return lista;
}
```

pronto, a consulta irá utilizar como critério somente o campo que vc preencher, caso omita os dois trará todos estados.

Foi isso que entendi do seu post, uma forma de criar uma consulta dinâmica na qual, eu como usuário da consulta posso omitir algum valor de parâmetro sem que isso gere um erro. Espero ter ajudado.